# How to change the values of two table automatically (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with two tables. The first one contains the user_name, user_password, user_email. The second one contains the user_name, user_age, user_description.

When a person finds the user he needs by the user_name, the script looks through the database using the user_name, to give out the information about certain user.

But if the person changes his user_name via preferences, the value changes only in the first table.

**Question:**

*1) Is there a way to make the user_name in the second table change automatically? (To connect them some how)*

I am using MySQL (phpMyAdmin).
This is just a simple example. In "real world" I am trying to manage more serious applications that have more tables. Is there an easier way than to  create a separate php query for each table?

Comment: What you need to use is called "triggers". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create an `AFTER UPDATE` MySQL trigger targeting single rows for this. [See the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html). It's probably not *easier* than using separate PHP queries for the tables, though. You don't need to spell them all out, just map up what needs to be synchronized when, and abstract your code.

However I'd recommend that you use a unique ID field for the user and only store the username in one of the tables -- and refer to the user with the ID under the hood of your code, and in both tables. Not a good idea to use something changeable as a unique identifier in your database design.